# R: replace variable name in batch

Tags: r, r-markdown

I am trying to update my variable names in the rmarkdown file, for example:

```
apple.table = matrix(10, 12, nrow=4)
apple.table[,2] = rep(0, 4)
```

I would like to change all `"apple.table"` into `"pear.table"`. Instead of manually copy and paste, is there an easier way to update the names in batch?

Comment: You can always use ctrl+f and replace all.

Comment: If you are using RStudio, you can also use the "Rename in Scope" option from the Code menu.  It doesn't understand scope in R Markdown properly, so you need to do it in each code chunk, but only once in each, and you don't need to worry about false matches like `apple.tablet` which might be caught by ctrl+f.

Comment: Also in RStudio, you can use "Replace and Find" from the "Edit" menu and that will give you various options. I like to us the "In Selection" option to highlight where I want to make the changes and then use the "Replace" and "all" options to do it all at once.